# How to creat a dynamic text

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a list of titles, and I would like these texts to alternate as I switch to ion-select. How do I do this?

I have no idea how to do this, not even what part of the code to show. I made an attempt here but whenever I use the console the value returned is undefined.

My typescrit code:

```
import { Titulo } from './../Services/services.service';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-libertacao',
  templateUrl: './libertacao.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./libertacao.page.scss'],
})

export class LibertacaoPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;
  PAGINA_SELECIONADA: number;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  index_atual: number;
  titulo: Titulo;
  constructor(private dataservice: DataService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute ){
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.titulo = this.dataservice.getTituloById(parseInt(id, 10));

  }
  OnChange(event: any)
  {
    if (event.detail.value === this.PAGINA_SELECIONADA) {
      this.slides.slideTo(this.PAGINA_SELECIONADA);
    }
    else {}
    console.log(this.titulo);

  }

  slideChanged() {
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index) => {
       this.index_atual = index;
    });
    }

}
```

Comment: Not getting what you are trying to explain..  please add html too and let us know what is the issue ..  how you are changing select box